# highcharts stacked column weird symbol in a bubble

Tags: highcharts

Please, check the screenshot below. I have an app that uses high charts and one of our customers sent a screenshot with a chart similar to this one asking what is this thing in the Apples column.

Can it be removed somehow?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the values for Apples is [1,0,0] which is kind of too small compared to other values. Try sharing the fiddle link and I can try fixing it

Comment: Correct. The "weird thing in a bubble" is the number zero being displayed over the tiny amount of data for that series.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to remove this overlap, you may try setting dataLabels.allowOverlap to false, or use formatter for showing only dataLabels if their values are greater than some other value: http://jsfiddle.net/64yphu8v/

Comment: Thank you! It's much easier to hunt it down when you know what it is :)